# How to solve the stochastic dynamic programming problem by value function iteration?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm trying to learn value function iteration by myself. Recently I'm solving this following problem:

Consider a real business cycle model with production function: $y_t=e^{a_t}k_t^{\alpha}$, where $a_t$ fluctuates overtime following a Markov process $\pi(a_{t+1}|a_t)$. The household's utility function is $u(c_t)=\dfrac{c_t^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}$ where $\gamma>0$ and $\gamma\neq 1$.

The Bellman equation should be (if I'm correct)
\begin{align*}
    v(k,a)=\max_{k'}\left[\frac{[e^a k^\alpha +(1-\delta)k-k']^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}+\beta\sum_{a'}P(a'|a)v(k',a')\right]
\end{align*}
Now let $\alpha=0.33,\delta=0.05,\beta=0.98,\gamma=2$. $a_t$ takes 2 possible values, $a_L=-0.3$ and $a_H=0.3$, where the conditional probability is
\begin{align*}
    \Pi=\begin{bmatrix}
        \pi_{HH}&\pi_{HL}\\
        \pi_{LH}&\pi_{LL}
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
        0.7&0.3\\0.4& 0.6
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
I want to solve the model numerically by value function iteration, but I'm stuck with a question: Now that the value function depends on both $k$ and $a$, how should I choose $v(k',a')$? Here's the `r` code I've written if it was a deterministic dynamic programming problem with the production function being $y=Ak^\alpha$:

```r
##Packages
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')
library('reshape2')

#Given values
A<-1
alpha<-0.33
delta<-0.05
beta<-0.98
gamma<-2


g<-function(kt){
  A*kt^alpha+(1-delta)*kt
} 


kseq<-seq(1,20,length.out=500) # The grid for k as a sequence from 1 to 20 with 500 points between them. As we have seen in question 2, the steady state of capital is around 10, so we want to make sure the grid for k covers the steady state.
pol<-rep(NA,length(kseq)) # The vector to store the policy function values
vseq<-rep(0,length(kseq)) # Initial value function
tvtemp<-matrix(NA,nrow=length(kseq),ncol=length(kseq)) # A matrix to store Tv values

for (h in 1:1000){ # 1000 iterations
  for (i in 1:length(kseq)){ #"i" is k
    for (j in 1:length(kseq)){ #"j" is k'
      if (g(kseq[i])-kseq[j]>=0){ # if consumption is positive
        tvtemp[i,j]=((g(kseq[i])-kseq[j])^(1-gamma))/(1-gamma)+beta*vseq[j] # compute Tv. How should vseq[j] be if the problem is stochastic?
      }
      else { # if consumption is negative, we don't want that
        tvtemp[i,j]=-Inf
      }
    }
  }
  tvseq<-apply(tvtemp,1,max) # find the maximum of the Tv sequence
  kprimepos<-apply(tvtemp,1,which.max) # find the index in which the maximum of the Tv sequence is located
  for (t in 1:length(kseq)){ # find the policy function value
    pol[t]<-nth(kseq,kprimepos[t])
  }
  epsilon<-max(abs(tvseq-vseq)) # let epsilon be the sup norm: epsilon = max |Tv-v|
  vseq=tvseq # set the value function vector to the computed Tv vector, and iterate again
}

epsilon # after 1000 iterations, epsilon = 0.000000001135803
```

However, I'm not sure how to solve the problem when one of the variables is stochastic. How should I modify the current code?